# distinct doesn't work for my query c# linq

Tags: c#, linq, distinct

I have this query as you can see here:

```
 public IQueryable<ViewReportMaterialRequestContractor> ShowReport(int MRCId)
        {
            var q = from m in _ctx.MaterialRequestContractorDetails
                    where m.MaterialRequestContractorId == MRCId

                    join mat in _ctx.MaterialDescriptions on m.MaterialDescriptionId equals mat.Id
                    join l in _ctx.Lines on m.LineId equals l.Id 
                    join joint in _ctx.Joints on m.LineId equals joint.LineId 


                    join sheet in _ctx.Sheets on joint.SheetId equals sheet.Id
                    join testjoint in _ctx.TestPackageJoints on joint.Id equals testjoint.Id

                    join testpack in _ctx.TestPackages on testjoint.TestPackageId equals testpack.Id
                    select new ViewReportMaterialRequestContractor()
                    {
                        Id = m.Id,
                        ItemCode = mat.ItemCode,
                        LineNumber = l.LineNumber,
                        Description = mat.Description,
                        Size1 = mat.Size1.ToString(),
                        Size2 = mat.Size2.ToString(),
                        DocumentNumber = l.DocumentNumber,

                    };
            return q;

        }
```

I call my function in the `UI` as you can see :

```
    List<ViewReportMaterialRequestContractor> lstMaterialRequestContractorDetails = _reportMaterialRequestContractorRepository.ShowReport(Id).ToList().Distinct().ToList();
```

My records repeat 4 times ,i have 4 records that repeat 4 times ,so i have 16 records .so i have to use distinct to remove duplicate records .

But the result shows 16 record again .Why?

Comment: How about removing `ToList` before `Distinct`

Comment: @IvanStoev let me check

Comment: @IvanStoev thanks it works ,But why?because i think the distinct clause should be executed and because of that i have distinct before that ,

Comment: Another thing to watch out for is the Id field you're selecting. Even if everything else is the same, different Ids means a distinct row. If you want to eliminate duplicate rows that only differ by Id, don't select the Id.

Comment: @IvanStoev out of curiosity, why removing `ToList()` makes this work? Wjy enumerating the query messes up `Distinct()`. Anonymous types perform value equality of all fields don't they?

Comment: It's because when you remove `ToList`, `Distinct` is tranlslated to SQL query and executed in the database. While with `ToList`, it's executed in memory and requires correct `GetHashCode` / `Equals` implementation, which I suppose your `ViewReportMaterialRequestContractor` class doesn't have.

Comment: @IvanStoev thanks, got it now. I misread the code and thought the query was returning an anonymous type collection. It's not my code or question btw.

Comment: @InBetween I know. But OP asked the same, so here you go :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `.ShowReport(Id).ToList().Distinct().ToList()` the `Distinct()` that is called is [`Enumerable.Distinct<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348436(v=vs.110).aspx), this creates a in-memory collection from the first `.ToList()` then does a distinct using the equality rules in .NET for the `ViewReportMaterialRequestContractor` class (which will be by default comparing by object references, not by values if you have not overridden `.Equals(object)` and `.GetHashCode()`)

When you do `.ShowReport(Id).Distinct().ToList()` the `Distinct()` that is called is [`Queryable.Distinct<TSource>(this IQueryable<TSource> source)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348456(v=vs.110).aspx), this converts the distinct in to a SQL query call and performs it on the server, using equality rules in SQL server (which will be comparing by values of each returned column)

Comment: But don't anonymous types implement automatically value equality comparing all fields? I was under the impression that the overrides `Equals` of the anonymous type would be used here.

Comment: @InBetween The OP did not make a annonamous type, the OP is working with a `ViewReportMaterialRequestContractor`, had the OP used a anonymous type I think the OP would have gotten the same behavior. To get the same behavior for the real type the OP will need to override `.Equals` and `.GetHashCode` for the `ViewReportMaterialRequestContractor` class so that it compares all the fields in the class when it checks for equality.

Comment: Duh, that's what happens when you read the code too fast. I thought it was an anonymous type, not an existing type. All clear now, thanks.

Comment: I think with anonymous types it would work; The compiler automatically overrides `Equals` to perform value comparison of all fields when it creates the class.

Comment: @InBetween yep, except the OP is returning the type in the function and you can't return anonymous types without casting them to `object` (or using `dynamic`).